# Let $M$ be a locally Noetherian module. Then, either $M$ is uniform or it has a uniform direct summand?

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Definition: An $R$-module $M$ is called *locally Noetherian* if, any finitely generated submodule of $M$ is Noetherian.

Question: **Let $M$ be a locally Noetherian module. Then, either $M$ is uniform or it  has a uniform direct summand?**

I don't have any idea about the existence or non-existence of above statement. Please guide me how to initiate.

Comment: What is the motivation for this question?  It seems extremely unlikely that it would have a positive answer, so how did it arise?  For example, a positive answer would imply that every Noetherian module is a direct sum of uniform modules.

Comment: Actually, we find a statement somewhere: Let $M$ be a locally Noetherian module. Then, $M$ has a maximal family $\{N_i:i\in I\}$ of uniform submodules such that $\oplus_{i\in I} N_i$ is local summand of $M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k$ be a field with an endomorphism $\phi$ such that $[k:\phi(k)]= n >1$.  Consider the twisted polynomial ring $k[x;\phi]$ where $xa:=\phi(a)x$ for all $a\in k$.  Let $R$ be the quotient ring by the ideal $(x^2)$.

Then $R$ is Artinian, hence locally Noetherian, considered as a right module over itself. It is  also local, so it has no proper summands.  But it is also not uniform, because it has distinct simple submodules.

Comment: @bipin I don’t know what you mean . Can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry. I was wrong. Every non-uniform module must have a nonzero proper complement submodule.

Comment: @bipin what’s your definition of proper complement submodule?

Comment: Let $N$, $L$ be two submodules of a module $M$. Then, $N$ is called a complement of $L$ (in $M$) if $N$ is maximal in the collection of submodules $Q$ of $M$ with the property $Q\cap L=0$. A submodule $K$ is called a complement submodule if it is a complement of some submodule of $M$.

Comment: Proper means not equal to the module.

Comment: @bipin Are you saying you wrote the question wrong? Because that ship has sailed already...

Comment: @bipin it’s obvious that in any module $M$, $M$ is uniform or $M$ contains a submodule with a nonzero proper complement.  This is because “uniform” means “all submodules are essential.” And if one is not essential, then it has a maximal complement by the usual Zorn argument...

Answer (score 3):

Any module over a Noetherian ring is locally Noetherian.  Let $K$ be a field and $R=K[x,y]/(x^2,xy)$.  We will abuse notation and denote the cosets of $x$ and $y$ by $x$ and $y$ respectively.  This is a famous example of a Noetherian ring with an embedded prime: the set of zero divisors in $R$ is precisely the ideal $(x,y)$.  We'll show $R$ is indecomposable as a module over itself but not uniform, thus showing the OP's question has a negative answer.

First suppose $R=I\oplus J$ for nonzero ideals $I,J$.  Then $IJ\subseteq I\cap J=0$, so $I,J$ both consist of zero divisors.  By the statement above, this implies $I+J\subseteq (x,y)$, and so we cannot have $R=I\oplus J$.  Next note that the ideal $(x)$ equals $Kx$ and the ideal $(y)$ equals $yK[y]$, whence $(x)\cap(y)=0$.  Thus ${}_RR$ is not uniform.